# Starting foreach at an index in python

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, numpy, append

I am reading in a tsv, running a web service to retrieve some information, and spitting this into a csv.

I have ran it for 4,610 lines of code and it has ran perfectly, however it seems to fail on line 4,611. I don't want to start running my code again from the beginning so how can I

- begin my "for" loop at index 4,611
- change it to append my information to the csv that is currently there
  instead of writing over it.

My code is as follows :

```
import csv
import GetAlexRanking #External Method exposed here
import subprocess
import pandas as p
import tai
import numpy as np

loadData = lambda f: np.genfromtxt(open(f,'r'), delimiter=' ')
with open('train.tsv','rb') as tsvin, open('PageRanks.csv', 'wb') as csvout:
    tsvin = list(np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,0])
    csvout = csv.writer(csvout)
    csvout.writerow(["URL","AlexaRank","GoogleRank"]) #writing
    for row in tsvin: #start in row 4,611
        count = 0
        sep = '|'
        row = row.split(sep, 1)[0]
        cmd = subprocess.Popen("python GetAlexRanking.py " + row ,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           shell=True)
        (output, err) = cmd.communicate()
        exit_code = cmd.wait()
        outlist = output.split('\r\n')
        try:
          outrank1 = outlist[1][outlist[1].index(':')+1:]
        except ValueError:
          outrank1 = "?"
        try:
          outrank2 = outlist[2][outlist[2].index(':')+1:]
        except ValueError:
          outrank2 = "?"
        csvout.writerow([str(outlist[0]), str(outrank1), str(outrank2)]) #is there a way to append here rather than write anew?
        count+=1
```

Any help would be muchly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do nothing for rows you've already processed:

```
i = 0
for row in tsvin:
    if i < 4611:
        continue
... the rest of your code
```

or even better, as suggested by @Joran:

```
for i,row in enumerate(tsvin):
```

Open file with append instruction:

```
open('PageRanks.csv', 'a')
```

Comment: you should really do `for i,row in enumerate(tsvin):` (+1 all the same)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Added to the answer, good one! Still in the process of embracing `enumerate` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import islice

START_AT = 4611
for i, row in enumerate(islice(tsvin, START_AT, None), START_AT):
    # ... your code here
```